# How to Draw 2 Functions In Tex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am aiming to plot a quadratic function and a s-curve as drawn [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PwWh.jpg) however I have not been able to get the lines to match up. Please assist if you could!

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
          xmax=10,ymax=10]
\addplot[green]  {x^2};
\addplot[blue,domain=1/2^6:10,samples=100]  {1/(1 + exp(-x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: what are the functions

Comment: Please provide the code you are using now, a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/26430)

Comment: @Oscar you also can take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426208/120578 because this post made me to write that question-answer (It will possibly help you to your other question too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
          domain=0:2,
          samples=100,
          ]
          \addplot[green]  {(x / 2)^2};
          \addplot[blue,]  {1/(1 + exp(-4 * (x - 1)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]